# line chart using arrays of an object using d3

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, d3.js, svg

I'm trying to create a line chart using d3 with the following object:

```
var data = {x: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],  y: [66, 67, 68, 68, 69, 70, 70, 75, 76, 78] }
```

This is the code I currently have to create the line:

```
<body>
<script>
var data = {x: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],  y: [66, 67, 68, 68, 69, 70, 70, 75, 76, 78] };
var w=400;
var h=50;

var line = d3.svg.line()
             .x(function(d,i){return x(d.x[i])})
             .y(function(d,i){return y(d.y[i])})
             .interpolate("linear");

var svg = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
            .attr({
            "width":w,
            "height":h
            })

var path = svg.append("path")
              .attr({
                d:line(data),
                "fill":"none",
                "stroke":"black"
              })

</script>
</body>
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: So what's your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key issue here is that the line generator expects an array where each item represents a point, not two arrays of x and y values. The accessor methods of the line generator allow you to set what properties of each object in the data array are used for x and  y values:

> When a line is generated, the x[/y] accessor will be invoked for each
>   defined element in the input data array, being passed the element d,
>   the index i, and the array data as three arguments. The default x[/y]
>   accessor assumes that the input data are two-element arrays of
>   numbers. ([source](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape#line_x))

So, we need to rearrange your data array from:

`{x: [1,2,3,4,5...], y: [1,2,3,4,5] }`

to:

`[{x:1,y:1},{x:2,y:2},{x:3,y:3}...]`

To do so we can use:

```js
var data = {x: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],  y: [66, 67, 68, 68, 69, 70, 70, 75, 76, 78] };

var rearrangedData = data.x.map(function(d,i) {
  return {x:d,y:data.y[i]}; 
})

console.log(rearrangedData);
```

Then we can display the line:

```js
var data = {x: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],  y: [66, 67, 68, 68, 69, 70, 70, 75, 76, 78] };
var w=400;
var h=200;

var rearrangedData = data.x.map(function(d,i) {
  return {x:d,y:data.y[i]}; 
})


var x = d3.scale.linear().domain([0,9]).range([0,w])
var y = d3.scale.linear().domain([65,80]).range([h,0])

var line = d3.svg.line()
             .x(function(d){ return x(d.x)})
             .y(function(d){return y(d.y)})
             .interpolate("linear");

var svg = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
            .attr({
            "width":w,
            "height":h
            })

var path = svg.append("path")
              .attr({
                "d":line(rearrangedData),
                "fill":"none",
                "stroke":"black"
              })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```